# SQL Server Pivot - Calculate Department Wise Monthly Attendance

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, biometrics, time-and-attendance

I am working on a query to get monthly attendance totals by department. i.e it will show present employees in each department based on attendance logs table where `check_type = 'C-IN'`

- Table 1: `checkin_out_log`

  - Columns: `emp_id`, `check_time`, `check_type` (C-IN, C-OUT)
- Table 2: `department`
- Table 3: `employee`

Expected output is

```
    Department | Total Staff | Date 1 | Date 2 | Date 3|......
    finance    | 60          | 50     | 55     | 48    |.....
```

Here is my query which is currently returning me total staff in each department,

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         d.id, d.name AS Department, T.DateToCheck,
         COUNT(e.id) AS staff
     FROM 
         employee e
     CROSS JOIN 
         (SELECT 
              CAST(DATEADD(DAY, number, @DateFrom) AS DATE) 
          FROM 
              master..spt_values 
          WHERE 
              type = 'P' 
              AND DATEADD(DAY, number, @DateFrom) <= @DateTo ) T (DateToCheck)
    LEFT JOIN 
        department d ON  d.id = e.department 
    WHERE
        d.id = 7
    GROUP BY 
        d.id, d.name, T.DateToCheck) T
PIVOT 
     (MAX(staff) 
         FOR DateToCheck IN ([2018-09-01],[2018-09-02],[2018-09-03],[2018-09-04],[2018-09-05],[2018-09-06],[2018-09-07],[2018-09-08],[2018-09-09],[2018-09-10],
[2018-09-11],[2018-09-12],[2018-09-13],[2018-09-14],[2018-09-15],[2018-09-16],[2018-09-17],[2018-09-18],[2018-09-19],[2018-09-20],[2018-09-21],[2018-09-22],[2018-09-23],
[2018-09-24],[2018-09-25],[2018-09-26],[2018-09-27],[2018-09-28],[2018-09-29],[2018-09-30])) P
;
```

Comment: Can't help but think you'd be better off putting your departments across the top, because they don't change often. Either that or making your calendar just the day number across the top 1..31 and not exact dates. I'd find changing this query every month to have the updated dates for this month, a massive pain in the ass..

Comment: What is your question, by the way?

Comment: I need to show present employees in each department based on attendance logs table

Comment: @CaiusJard no its not the case, this query is basically a result of a dynamic query which generates dynamic dates based on the range supplied, so issue at all on date columns

Comment: Ugh, I had a feeling the word "dynamic" was going to creep in..

Comment: Is the 'biometrics' tag applicable to this question? I cannot discern that.